# Flexbox CSS - growing a box to fit content, without affecting other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to force the bottom-most row (in yellow) to "expand downward" to fill available content:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/oucvnfke/

I had assumed that this could be done by using:

`flex: auto;`

I'm open to .js solutions to this issue, but if there is a pure css solution that is obviously ideal. I'm hoping that I do not have to change my HTML markup.

The idea is that I have a fixed top container (light green), and a bottom container that can grow to accommodate the content, even though the bottom container is split into 2 columns.,

Comment: First you have to make the ton of parent containers also fill the available space. An element that's set to grow to the bottom of its parent will not push the parent's bottom down. Start with `html, body { margin: 0, height: 100vh }`

Comment: May I ask why you have nested `col` and wrappers all over? Your markup could be simplified a lot, if all you need is a upper green and 2 lower, side-by-side, both taking up equal height all the way to the bottom, and then grow with content

Comment: I agree that the markup could be simplified. Unfortunately, this is what I was given to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex: 1 0 100%` on `.row` instead.

```css
.wrapper-row {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

/* the top row must always be 50px, regardless of the bottom content */
.top-row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex-basis: 50px;
}

.bottom-row {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: auto;
  /* this should allow bottom row to expand */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper-row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row top-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row bottom-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-6 bottom-left-col">
              <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-6 bottom-right-col">
              <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                  This content should be entirely contained within the yellow region, on account of flex: auto. Why isn't it?
                  <br />
                  <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum tortor in felis porttitor, at elementum massa vestibulum. Suspendisse lobortis tempor tellus.
                  <br />
                  <br />Donec aliquam laoreet tortor ut vulputate. Proin est ipsum, vehicula id lacus pharetra, dictum fringilla magna. Integer mollis nunc quis leo porttitor congue. Nam a nulla eget ipsum congue dapibus. Proin in elit iaculis tortor pretium
                  ullamcorper. Etiam cursus consequat vehicula. Suspendisse fermentum ante eu sodales mollis.

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .row { ... flex: 1; ...} will suffice (the same goes for .col )

Comment: It looks like "flex: 1 0 1;" actually works better for some reason. The 100% value didn't work properly in Safari.

Comment: @DarrenGates cool do you want to edit my answer? Feel free to do it and I'll approve it.

Comment: No, it's still good. I think that the % thing is a Safari bug.